# Get local IP with CloseableHttpAsyncClient with multiple NICs

Tags: java, apache, http

I have Linux & Mac OS X clients with multiple NICs, each of those NICs may be connected to Internet/Intranet in various combinations.

Pure Java client application utilizes 'CloseableHttpAsyncClient' without specifying which local IP to use. 
When I receive an HTTP response I need to find out which local IP (NIC) used to route to the destination host.
Is it possible to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best I could do is to use a custom builder with 'setEventHandler' and overriding 'responseReceived (NHttpClientConnection conn)'.

From 'conn' I could read private 'IOSession' field (thanks to reflection) and it usually contains local IP.